# Windows PowerShell Batch File Rename

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, optimization

Currently, I manually go through each file and update it using the common rename procedure.
I am just starting to try and figure out how to use Windows PowerShell in order to rename a bunch of files with a common structure.  The problem is, all the examples I've seen use a common extension to replace something.  I want to remove everything after an extension, and am getting errors.

Examples:

```
64244350.NSFM3V@.NO_BATCHES.20150108073838322
64244882.NSFM3V@.NO_BATCHES.20150108073534804
```

What I would like it to end up like is:

```
64244350.NSFM3V
64244882.NSFM3V
```

The .NSFM3V is the common factor in ALL the files, but there is randomness before and after.  Here is my first attempt at creating something in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem *.NSFM3V* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_name -Replace *.{$_name}.*,""}
```

My Get-ChildItem *.NSFM3V* works in grabbing all the files from the folder, but I can't get it to rename.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
gci *.NSFM3V* | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '(.*)@.*', '$1' }
```

Use a regular expression to get the left hand side of the `@` and use it in the replacement.

#### Explanation:

- Any match from `gci` is passed to the pipeline, the object that is passed is given the special variable `$_`
- `Rename-Item` takes the object `$_` from the pipeline and uses the substition inside `{..}` to craft the new name
- The regex inside the `-replace` takes the `name` property of the object and applies the substitution
- `(.*)` means match *anything*. Note the brackets, these are important as they form a **capturing group**
- `@.*` means match `@` followed by *anything*
- that means when combined, capture anything up to a `@` followed by anything
- `'$1'` is the reference to the capture group, so essentially you replace the entire `$_.name` value with everything up to (the last) `@` and pass that to the `-NewName` parameter

Comment: This works great! Thank you!

Do you mind explaining it a bit? I would like to understand in case I need to tweak it for other files.  

the $_.name takes the current GetChildItem right? and then replaces the text using the commands after?  Not sure how to interpret the next part 
'(.*)@.*', '$1' }

Comment: Wondering if you can recheck my comment and provide some insight when you get a chance? Thanks!

Comment: I wish I had more rep so I could bump you up some!  Thanks, that helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternate approach without using the regular expression approach which is often pain to read/understand.

```
Get-ChildItem *.NSFM3V* | Rename-Item -NewName {($_.Name -split "@")[0]}
```

Cheers,
GJ

Comment: Can you explain a bit how the part {($_.Name -split "@")[0]} works?

Comment: We use the `-split` to split the `$_.name` object with the delimiter as `@`. So your file name is now split into two parts `64244882.NSFM3V` and `.NO_BATCHES.20150108073534804`. Since we are interested only in the 1st part we use the array index which is [0](in PS index always start with 0). Hope this helps. You could read more about splitting techniques in powershell help `help about_split`